# How can I change build-in tooltip of ZoomControl (from wpfextensions)?

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, wpf-extended-toolkit

I'm using library which using [WPFEextensions](https://wpfextensions.codeplex.com/).
On mouse over ZoomControl there's tooltip in English (how to use zoom):
[image: scree]
I want to change it to another language or write a custom tooltip message.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [fork](https://wpfextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/borys_lebeda/localization) in which that bug fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several (not such good) options:
 - template;
 - style;
 - on init manually find element from visual tree and update tooltip value;

Comment: There is one flaw with all of these methods: default tooltip shows up first, and after that my overriding value applies.